# Color-magnetic fields in quark-gluon plasma?

Tags: quark-gluon-plasma

I was curious as to whether there is a color equivalent of magnetic field in CCD. The answers here suggest there is, but only at femtometre scales due to confinement. Is this the case also for the quark-gluon plasmas postulated in neutron stars and the early universe?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is models all the way, but yes. [Here the analog](https://indico.cern.ch/event/630495/contributions/2550027/attachments/1456874/2255277/5-Kazunori.Itakura.pdf) of the QED magnetic field is called Glasma !

> Strong color electromagnetic fields (Glasma)

> -remnant of the colliding CGCs (saturated gluonicstates)

> -can be treated as weak-coupling, classical fields

> -decay rapidly

etc. etc.

Also [here](https://inspirehep.net/files/f9dfdcd2bd2ad78fb4df273217c2c0c8)  by the same author.

> Ordinary electromagnetic fields and non-Abelian color Yang-Mills fields called a glasma.I explain how they are created in collisions, how strong they are, and how important

As far as I found out, it is a model to be applied to the quark gluon plasma studied at LHC , but I expect if successful it would apply for the quark-gluon plasma in cosmology too.